# Assign different values to each zone, ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, cost-path

Is it possible to assign different values to each zone. The value would be decimal.

100==> 4.97
200==> 5.90
300==> 6.01
..ect...
1000==> 9.64
or somehow change value with cost raster.
I have DEM raster, buffer raster, reclass raster, poligon layer.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Spatial Analyst, you can use [Reclassify tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) to change the old pixel values to new values.

However, The tool may not work with decimals (I did not test it with decimals), but I know it works with integer values. You can try with decimals, if it did not work, then multiply the new values with 100 to make it integer.

For example, use `100 -> 497` `(integer)` instead of `100 -> 4.97` `(decimal)`. Then using raster calculator divide the output by 100 to get the values in decimals.

Comment: Reclassiy tool does not work with decimals. If there is no other option, your answer looks good.

Comment: Use lookup in reclassify

Comment: Do you have an example with lookup class?

Comment: When I divide with raster calculator (1245/100=12) result is 12 not 12.45. It is rounded.

Comment: @nagib you need to convert the raster type from integer to float before dividing by 100. Use Float() function from raster calculator to convert the reclassified raster into float type, then divide by 100.

Comment: Yes, that is it. I think it is forbidden to thank 